# Heroku app successfully deploying, but showing application error when loading the site

Tags: python, heroku

Below you can find the logs. Am I missing something here?

```
    -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
    -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
    -----> Python app detected
    -----> No Python version was specified. Using the same version as the last build: python-3.10.5
           To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
    -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
    -----> Using cached install of python-3.10.5
    -----> Installing pip 22.1.2, setuptools 60.10.0 and wheel 0.37.1
    -----> Installing SQLite3
    -----> Installing requirements with pip
           Ignoring backports.zoneinfo: markers 'python_version < "3.9"' don't match your environment
    -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
           Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/cancel.js'. It will be ignored since only the first
encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make
sure every static file has a unique path.
           Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/popup_response.js'. It will be ignored since only the
first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want,
make sure every static file has a unique path.
           1451 static files copied to '/tmp/build_9c61124b/static_cdn', 111 unmodified.
    -----> Discovering process types
    -----> Compressing...
           Done: 116.3M
    -----> Launching...
           Released v13
           https://dgrealstate.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
    This app is using the Heroku-20 stack, however a newer stack is available.
    To upgrade to Heroku-22, see:
    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack
```

Comment: It's not successfully deploying. Look at your build log it contains more extensive information. Also your current log is pointing to possible errors. But without you providing any information it's not possible to help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That's your _build_ log, but the build is succeeding. You need to look at your _runtime_ logs, e.g. by running `heroku logs`.